# Unlocking computer takes really long time when scaling is enabled

Tags: 16.04, lock-screen, scaling, unlock

I have problem with unlocking of my machine running Ubutnu 16.04 LTS. It's almost fresh installation (few weeks old) and I have problem with really slow unlocking (tens of seconds). I have enabled scaling in `Settings` - `Display`s by setting `Scale for menu and title bars` to `0.875` and I think it is cause of my problem.

When I lock my computer, the lockscreen is scaled as expected, but if I leave computer for some time and return back, lock screen sometimes resets to original scaling and during unlocking, it scales back to my value 0.875 and I think it causes my problem. Why scaling sometimes reset for lockscreen? Could it be a bug in Unity/Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you checked to see whether your hard drive is using Power Management?   If you are, then it is normal to have to wait a few seconds for it to spin up.

Comment: It is SSD, but I can definitely check it, but I'm not sure how